# How to avoid soft keyboard pushing up / covering my layout?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

i'm looking for a solution to make my webview wrapped in relative layout be pushed off the screen from the top and and be squished or be overlayed by the soft keyboard. Ive used adjustPan in the current state, the dream state is what i want to achieve. Using adjustResize squishes my webview, to adjust for the lost height by the keyboard, I don't want that either. I prefer the ios way of pushing the entire webview up, so that the action bar overshoots the screen boundaries (if required).

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.in.thewizards.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Was just reading an article about this. See if this https://saket.me/smoothly-reacting-to-keyboard/ helps.

Comment: Thank you for redirecting me to a 404 page

Comment: Sorry, updated the link.

Comment: adjustResize is an easier way to go, if I wanted to resize my viewport

Answer (score 0):

Use adjustResize value for your activity in AndroidManifest.xml
Like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".presentationLayer.screens.chatScreen.view.ChatScreenActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/App.NoActionBar.Theme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Comment: like i said i DO NOT want to use adjustResize as it resizes my webview

Answer (score 0):

add this in your manifest

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"    
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Comment: adjustpan gives the current state and not the dream state, like i mentioned in the question

Comment: try with different options of windowSoftInputMode.single option of windowSoftInputMode and multi option